# Como fazer uma busca na tabela com o SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Bom galera, como eu faço para fazer um select em uma tabela utilizando o SQLite no Android? Até o momento eu tenho a tabela criada e o insert.

Por exemplo: buscar pelo o login e senha do Usuário, para poder comparar.

Segue os código:

BancoDados:

```
public class BancoDados extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String NOME_BANCO = "banco.db";
    public static final String NOME_TABELA = "usuario";
    public static final int VERSAO_BANCO = 1;

    public BancoDados(Context context) {
        super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO_BANCO);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase bd) {
        bd.execSQL("create table if not exists " +
                "usuario(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nome text not null," +
                "login text not null," +
                " senha text not null," +
                " email text not null);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase bd, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

ControleBanco:

```
public class ControleBanco {
    private SQLiteDatabase bd;
    private BancoDados banco;

    public ControleBanco(Context context) {
        banco = new BancoDados(context);
    }

    public String inserirDados(String nome, String login, String senha, String email) 
{
        long resultado;
        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
        bd = banco.getWritableDatabase();
        valores.put("nome", nome);
        valores.put("login", login);
        valores.put("senha", senha);
        valores.put("email", email);

        resultado = bd.insert(BancoDados.NOME_TABELA, "", valores);
        bd.close();
        if (resultado == -1) {
            return "Falha ao cadastrar";
        } else {
            return "Cadastrado com sucesso";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue abaixo o código do método responsável por pegar um registro do banco e retornar um usuário como resposta. Qualquer dúvida, comenta aí!

```
public Usuario pegarUsuarioPorEmail(String email){

    Usuario u;  
    bd = banco.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT nome, login, senha, email FROM usuario WHERE email = ?", new String[] {email});
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){

        u = new Usuario();
        u.setNome(cursor.getString(0));
        u.setLogin(cursor.getString(1));
        u.setSenha(cursor.getString(2));
        u.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
    } else {
        u = null;
    }

    cursor.close();
    bd.close();

    return u;
}
```

Na sua MainActivity:

```
private Usuario recuperarUsuario(String email){

   ControleBanco banco = new ControleBanco(this);

   Usuario u = banco.pegarUsuarioPorEmail(email);

   return u;
}
```

EDIT:
O problema que você está enfrentando é porque a partir do android studio 3.0, o mecanismo de sintaxe para query sql ficou mais rigoroso. Uma das soluções apontadas por alguns usuários e que pode funcionar é a seguinte.
Mude este trecho de código:

```
Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT nome, login, senha, email FROM usuario WHERE email = ?", new String[] {email});
```

para este:

```
String querySql = "SELECT nome, login, senha, email FROM usuario WHERE email = ?";
Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery(querySql, new String[] {email});
```

Parece uma alteração boba e que não faz a menor diferença, mas alguns usuários afirmaram que dessa forma a consulta funciona. Teste e me diga se funcionou. OBS: Lembre de testar sem as aspas simples e caso não funcione, teste com as aspas simples.

Comment: Nesta parte: mail FROM usuario WHERE email = ?", a interrogação tem aspas simples? E como eu poderia manipular esses dados que retornam na minha activity?

Comment: Esse interrogação está dando problema no meu aqui

Comment: @ChristianGomesdaSilva editei minha resposta com um exemplo de como chamar o método na sua activity para trabalhar com os dados recuperados.

Comment: @ChristianGomesdaSilva não está funcionando? Testei aqui e funcionou. Qual versão do android studio está utilizando? Testei esse código no android studio versão 2.3.3;
É provável (não tenho certeza) que na versão 3.0.0 do android studio precise colocar aspas simples na interrogação.

Comment: @ChristianGomesdaSilva se não funcionar colocando aspas simples na interrogação, posta o erro aqui nos comentários pra eu ver o que pode ser.

Comment: Dá esse erro <expr> expected, got '?'

Comment: @ChristianGomesdaSilva certo. Dei uma pesquisada nos fóruns americanos e descobri que a partir do android studio 3.0 o mecanismo de sintaxe para query sql ficou mais rigoroso e algumas pessoas estão tendo o mesmo problema que você. Editei minha resposta com uma das soluções que alguns usuários apontaram e que pode funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
public boolean pesquisar(String texto){

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE texto= '"+texto+"'";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlSelect,null);

    if(c.getCount()>0){
        return true;
    }

    c.close();
    db.close();

    return false;
}
```